# When the given invariant subring is isomorphic to a polynomial ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I met the following exercise in my algebra course:

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n],(n\geq 2)$, and consider a map $\varphi: R\rightarrow R$, defined by
$$\varphi(P)(x_1,...,x_n):=P(\zeta_m^{a_1}x_1,...,\zeta_m^{a_n}x_n),$$
where $\zeta_m:=e^{2\pi i/m},(m\geq 2)$, and $a_j\in \{0,1\}$. Let
$$R':=\{P\in R: P=\varphi(P)\}.$$
This is a subring of $R$ (which is a part of exercise, somewhat routine). The question is: determine when the subring $R'$ is isomorphic to a full polynomial ring over $\mathbb{C}$.

Indeed I didn't even know how to think about this exercise (Galois theory, or commutative algebra?). The fraction field of $R$ is $F=\mathbb{C}(x_1,...,x_n)$, and the map $\varphi$ uniquely determines a field automorphism. Then when $a_j\in \{0,1\}$, it gives an action of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ on $F$. Then $R'$ is the intersection of the fixed field and $R$.

Without loss of generality, up to permutation it suffices to consider the case
$$a_1,...,a_k=1; a_{k+1},...,a_n=0.$$
I know that in this case the fixed field is exactly
$$K=\mathbb{C}\left( x_1^m,\frac{x_2}{x_1},...,\frac{x_k}{x_1},x_{k+1},...,x_n\right)$$
But then, when is $K\cap \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ isomorphic to a polynomial ring?

I have no idea. Maybe this exercise is related to some background in algebraic geometry? Any suggestion or hint is welcome. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @ThePhoenix Oh thanks, I made a serious typo: I forgot to add $x_1^ m$! I've added it. Then it's an exercise by using Artin's theorem in Galois theory to show that this is exactly the invariant subfield of the action of $\mathbb{ Z}/m$ since the degree over this subfield is $ m$.

Comment: @ThePhoenix I didn't really understand your final argument:  you have at hand these generators and you found that they are not algebraically independent. But how can you promise there's no other choice of generators that are independent? Maybe I need such an argument: if the set of generators are minimal and not algebraically independent, then it can't be isomorphic to a polynomial ring. But I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: @ThePhoenix Oh That's the point. Thanks!